# Error:generic parameter 'T' cannot be inferred.

Tags: ios, swift, generics

```
public extension NSEntityDescription {
public class func insertNewObjectForNamedEntity<T:NSManagedObject where T:NamedEntity>(namedEntity: T.Type, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> T {
    return self.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(namedEntity.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! T
}
}
```

This is part of my code. Then I call this function in another file, like this:

```
var category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForNamedEntity(Category.self, inManagedObjectContext: mainQueueContext)
```

But it says: generic parameter 'T' cannot be inferred. 
About the class `Category`:

```
class Category: NSManagedObject, NamedEntity {
class var entityName: String
    {
    return "Category"
}
}
```

Can anyone give me some hints about this error?

Comment: Actually your code compiles without problems for me (if the NamedEntity protocol is defined properly).

Comment: Thanks. This error just gone and I don't know why......